# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, statistics, moderation

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Web Applications breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  6         14
Users destroyed                                 165          0
Users deleted                                     4          0
Users contacted                                   8          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           199      1,657
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               31         64
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        346      2,147
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue              148      1,101
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               162      4,172
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue            1,030      2,028
Tag synonyms proposed                             0          1
Revisions redacted                                7          0
Questions unprotected                             3          2
Questions reopened                               13          1
Questions protected                               1        235
Questions migrated                              182          5
Questions merged                                  2          0
Questions flagged⁴                               49      2,109
Questions closed                              1,350        160
Question flags handled⁴                         493      1,665
Posts unlocked                                    2         31
Posts undeleted                                  27         38
Posts locked                                      5        822
Posts deleted⁵                                1,611      2,888
Posts bumped                                      0      4,717
Escalations to the CM team                        3          0
Comments undeleted                                4          0
Comments flagged                                  0        849
Comments deleted⁶                               520      1,543
Comment flags handled                           458        391
Bounties canceled                                 1          0
Answers flagged                                 144      4,897
Answer flags handled                          4,049        992
All comments on a post moved to chat              1          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...