# 2022: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

As we say goodbye to the old year and welcome the new one, we have [a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the preceding calendar year](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

As most of you here are aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

That doesn't eliminate the need for having [moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference.

So as we say goodbye to 2022 (and where did January go, right?) and dive head first into 2023, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some [*exciting* stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0TPg.gif). Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Web Applications over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Answer flags handled | 865 | 351 |
| Answers flagged | 80 | 1,135 |
| Bounties canceled | 1 | 0 |
| Comment flags handled | 88 | 110 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 115 | 775 |
| Comments flagged | 35 | 162 |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 1 | 0 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 6,954 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 560 | 2,280 |
| Posts locked | 1 | 364 |
| Posts undeleted | 2 | 49 |
| Posts unlocked | 0 | 10 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 179 | 217 |
| Questions closed | 696 | 11 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 44 | 371 |
| Questions migrated | 122 | 0 |
| Questions protected | 0 | 115 |
| Questions reopened | 6 | 0 |
| Questions unprotected | 0 | 1 |
| Revisions redacted | 1 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Close votes" queue | 37 | 131 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "First answers" queue | 34 | 611 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "First questions" queue | 5 | 1,239 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Late answers" queue | 8 | 465 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Low quality posts" queue | 59 | 261 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Reopen votes" queue | 15 | 20 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Suggested edits" queue | 193 | 475 |
| Users destroyed³ | 42 | 0 |
| Users suspended² | 0 | 49 |

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes). Community can handle these flags by at least one person voting to close a question that has a close flag.

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: [2021: a year in moderation](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4850/2021-a-year-in-moderation)
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222022%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386090/208518)

Wishing everyone a happy 2023! ^_^

Answer (score 2):

What I noticed about the stats:

- The 696:11 Questions Closed by Moderators to Questions Closed by Community ratio is very high.
- The 707:6 Questions Closed to Questions Reopened ratio is also very high.
- The Community reopened **zero** questions in the past year.

Web Apps SE seems to lack active users with sufficient rep to close/reopen questions. Or are these stats typical of SE sites?

Also, Web Apps SE appears to be more stringent than most other SE sites about which questions should be left open, which contributes to the lack of activity and high-rep active users. Is this site more stringent than other SE sites, or do its stats reflect the norm?

Comment: I don't have the answers to those questions off the top of my head, but you can look through a random sample of this post on other sites and draw conclusions yourself ^_^

Comment: Agreed, the 696:11 Questions Closed by Moderators to Questions Closed by Community ratio is alarmingly high. I believe mods too often closes valid questions e.g. https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4794/18147

Answer (score 0):

Below there are some numbers about the tags that had more than 50 questions during 2022

| **TagName** | **Questions** | **Unanswered** | **Zero Answers** | **Answers** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **google-sheets** | 1181 | 638 | 236 | 1420 |
| **gmail** | 170 | 119 | 93 | 270 |
| **facebook** | 136 | 127 | 116 | 144 |
| **google-docs** | 84 | 46 | 35 | 133 |
| **youtube** | 80 | 67 | 55 | 120 |
| **google-drive** | 65 | 44 | 34 | 83 |

Source: [Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/1702029/questions-and-answers-by-tag?Year=2022)

---

Notes:

The following tags were excluded because they are commonly used together with one or more of the above tags

google-apps-script,
formulas,
google-sheets-query,
google-sheets-arrayformula,
google-sheets-dates,
conditional-formatting,
google

---

Questions: Includes deleted questions.

Unanswered: Open questions having no acepted answer, no answers with positive score or not having any answer.

Zero answers: Open questions having no answers.

Answers: Includes deleted answers.

---

Sample searches

- Questions: [[google-drive] created:2022 is:question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-drive%5D%20created%3A2022%20is%3Aquestion)
- Unanswered: [[google-drive] created:2022 is:question isanswered:0](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-drive%5D%20created%3A2022%20is%3Aquestion%20isanswered%3A0)
- Zero answers: [[google-drive] created:2022 is:question answers:0](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-drive%5D%20created%3A2022%20is%3Aquestion%20answers%3A0)
- Answers: [[google-drive] created:2022 is:answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-drive%5D%20created%3A2022%20is%3Aanswer)